# ExoPlayer not loading subtitles from .srt file

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, video-subtitles

So I am trying to show subtitles from my .srt file in exoplayer but it does not work.
Do I need to use a seperate SubtitleView to get my subtitles to show up?
Is the subtitleView in the PlayerView is not enough?
I use PlayerView btw.

The exoplayer version I use is 2.14.0.

The addTextOutput method.

```java
simpleExoPlayer.addTextOutput(cues -> {
                playerView.getSubtitleView().setCues(cues);
                playerView.getSubtitleView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                playerView.getSubtitleView().onCues(cues);
                assert cues.get(0).text != null;
                Log.d("subtitles", cues.get(0).text.toString());
            });
```

I also tried to implement to `TextOutput` but that did not work too.

The contents of my sample.srt file:

```
1
00:00:00,000 --> 00:00:01,500
For www.forom.com

2
00:00:01,500 --> 00:00:02,500
<i>Tonight's the night.</i>

3
00:00:03,000 --> 00:00:15,000
<i>And it's going to happen
again and again --</i>
```

The function I use to load my subtitles:

```java
public void buildMediaSourceV3(Uri uri){
        String subtitlesUri = sharedPreferencesSubtitles.getString(videoName.getText().toString(), "");

        DataSource.Factory factory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(VideoPlayer.this, getPackageName(), new DefaultBandwidthMeter());
        MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);
        MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
        if(subtitlesUri.equals(""))
        {
            simpleExoPlayer.addMediaSource(videoSource);
        }
        else
        {
                MediaItem.Subtitle subtitle = new  MediaItem.Subtitle(Uri.parse(subtitlesUri), MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP, "en");
                MediaSource textMediaSource = new SingleSampleMediaSource.Factory(factory).createMediaSource(subtitle, C.TIME_UNSET);
                textMediaSource.getMediaItem().mediaMetadata.subtitle.toString();
                MergingMediaSource mergingMediaSource = new MergingMediaSource(videoSource, textMediaSource);
                simpleExoPlayer.addMediaSource(mergingMediaSource);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Here is minimal example for video/mp4 with SRT subtitles. For XML layout is used com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.StyledPlayerView and there is no need for additional subtitle layout. Files are located in assets directory inside the project.

```
    val playerView = view.findViewById<StyledPlayerView>(R.id.video_pv)
    val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(requireActivity()).build()
    playerView.player = exoPlayer

    val assetSrtUri = Uri.parse(("file:///android_asset/subtitle.srt"))
    val subtitle = SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(assetSrtUri)
        .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)
        .setLanguage("en")
        .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
        .build()

    val assetVideoUri = Uri.parse(("file:///android_asset/video.mp4"))
    val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
        .setUri(assetVideoUri)
        .setSubtitleConfigurations(ImmutableList.of(subtitle))
        .build()

    exoPlayer.setMediaItem(mediaItem)

    exoPlayer.prepare()
    exoPlayer.play()
```

Gradle dependencies:

```
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.17.1"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.17.1"
implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.17.1"
```

Comment: Thanks, this fix worked for me using v1.0.0 of the new Media3 ExoPlayer, I was missing the `.setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)` and `.setLanguage("en")` lines

Answer (score 3):

I know you've already implemented [a workaround](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/9021#issuecomment-881284633).

I've just encountered the same issue, and found a solution:

```
trackSelector.setPreferredTextLanguage
```

This helped me. Full context:

```
val trackSelector = DefaultTrackSelector(context)
trackSelector.setParameters(trackSelector.buildUponParameters().setPreferredTextLanguage("en"))
```

**Update:**
I was wrong. That solution shows only video embedded captions, not the sideloading ones.

This works for me now:

```
val mediaItemBuilder = MediaItem.Builder()
                .setUri(uri))

videoCaption?.vtt?.let {
    val uriSubtitle = Uri.parse(it)
    val mediaItemSubtitle = MediaItem.Subtitle(uriSubtitle,
                            MimeTypes.TEXT_VTT,
                            "en",
                            C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
            
        
    mediaItemBuilder.setSubtitles(mutableListOf(mediaItemSubtitle))
}
        
val mediaItem = mediaItemBuilder.build()
val mediaSource = DefaultMediaSourceFactory(dataSourceFactory, extractoryFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the builder to add in the subtitles...

```
val assetSrtUri = Uri.parse("https:.........")
val subtitle = MediaItem.SubtitleConfiguration.Builder(assetSrtUri)
               .setMimeType(MimeTypes.APPLICATION_SUBRIP)
               .setLanguage("en")
               .setSelectionFlags(C.SELECTION_FLAG_DEFAULT)
               .build()

val firstVideoUri = Uri.parse(intent.getStringExtra(ARG_VIDEO_URL))
val firstItem = MediaItem.Builder().setUri(firstVideoUri)
firstItem.setSubtitleConfigurations(ImmutableList.of(subtitle))
player.addMediaItem(firstItem.build())
player.prepare()
```